# Selenium-IDE: Make a .java file run in the FireFox Extension

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I'm new with Selenium and the documentation I can find doesn't really help.

I have recorded a script/test in the Firefox extension, then exported it into a .java file and edited it to include assertions. Now I have no idea how to get the test back into Selenium IDE as I get an error message saying command not found.

Due to internet security issues I cannot run the Selenium Server via cmd and run the tests through Eclipse or I would.

The question is: Is there a way to run a .java or .jar through the firefox extension of Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to import your file back into Selenium IDE.  Once you export, it's in WebDriver format, which is completely seperate from the Selenium IDE format.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Do you know of any documentation or reference for writing directly into the IDE instead of exported to Java for things like assertions?

Comment: Well, i might be biased, but i'd recommend you start out using pure Selenium WebDriver.  Record and playback is typically frowned upon in web automation.  If you are doing short tasks, then the IDE is perfect, but not if you want to do advanced things.  Check out http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium-framework